# Calculate vector unit without square root

Tags: math, vector, language-agnostic, trigonometry

I need to calculate the unit vector for arbitrary vectors. The clue is that I don't want to introduce floating point errors, so I can't afford to use the sqrt() function. In order to do arithmetic and don't introduce floating point errors, I use a Rational datatype.

```
public class Vector3
{
    public Rational X { get; set; }
    public Rational Y { get; set; }
    public Rational Z { get; set; }

    public Vector3(Rational x, Rational y, Rational z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
    .....
```

and my vector unit calculation looks like this:

```
    public Vector3 Unit()
    {
        if (this.Length() == 0)
            return new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        return this.DividedBy(this.Length());
    }

    public Rational Length()
    {
        return Sqrt(Dot(this).ToDouble());
    }

    public Rational Dot(Vector3 a)
    {
        return this.X * a.X + this.Y * a.Y + this.Z * a.Z;
    }
```

The problem is the Sqrt() method because I have to convert my Rational to a double. Moreover, the Sqrt() produces an irrational number. So I have a possible roundoff error in the input and in the ouput of the sqrt function.

So I need to calculate the length of the vector without a square root. Is that possible?

Comment: Imagine that the length of your vector is exactly `sqrt(2)/2)`. This cannot be notated as a rational value, so what you are aiming for is impossible in at the very least, the general case. If you have a specialized vector set `V such that for all v in V, |v| is in Q`, then you might have an argument against the use of the `sqrt()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do what you want here, because square roots are generally (and famously) irrational.

If you want to stick with exact arithmetic, you may be able to handle it by keeping your higher-order values around as is, in a sort of extended rational datastructure -- a kind of algebraic geometry thing.  This path has its limitations, as the polynomial order of your results is generally the sum of the order of the arguments...

I think [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) provides something like this as an option.  In any case, if you're interested in geometric math, but worried about floating point errors, taking a look at CGAL should be an education.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it can't be done without square roots.  Your fears of round off errors are overblown.

You can do the calculation in such a way to minimize the errors, like this  (Java-ish syntax; no such Math.max in the JDK, but you get the idea):

```
public double magnitude(double x, double y, double z) {
    double maxComponent = Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y), Math.abs(z));
    double rx = x/maxComponent;
    double ry = y/maxComponent;
    double rz = z/maxComponent;
    return maxComponent*Math.sqrt(rx*rx + ry*ry + rz*rz);
}
```

Comment: `Math.max(Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y)), Math.abs(z))` would be the preferred function call in Java, I believe. Unfortunately, no variadic max function exists. This does appear to minimize FP errors. A +1 to you.

Comment: I believe I said that in my answer.  I know it doesn't exist.  You'd have to write it.

Comment: I can see how this avoids overflow, but why do you think it minimizes round off errors?

Comment: What a pitty. I would accept your answer but I can't agree with this sentence: "Your fears of round off errors are overblown.". Well roundoff errors are much more problematic as you might think. Especially when it comes to testing for equality or making predicates (i.e. if a point lies to the right or left of a line).

Answer (score 1):

If the problem you are solving is THAT sensitive to floating point errors (I have dealt with some before), is it possible for you to specify the level of tolerance you are willing to live with? For example set it at the accuracy of the input data set?

Assuming that is possible, my suggestion would be to replace the sqrt(x) call with an approximation that is known to be accurate up to a certain tolerance.

For example you could approximate it as the solution to the root-finding problem X^2 - S = 0. Given that the function is strictly increasing and well behaved on the positive half-plane, you could implement say a bisection or Newton-Raphson method and terminate it based on the tolerance.

Hope you find this useful even if it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the sqrt can be removed:

For vector functions that usually require a unit vector you can sometimes get around the sqrt with a little clever math. Vector projection is a good example.

Projecting vector a onto vector b with sqrt:

- **(a / sqrt( dot( b, b ) ) * b**

Projecting vector a onto vector b without sqrt:

- **( dot( a, b ) / dot( b, b ) ) * b**

The extra dot(a,b) removes the need for a sqrt.
But does cost 3 multiples and 2 adds (for a vector 3) so it isn't free.